# how to use the GNU hcreate_r

Tags: c, gnu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <search.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *data[] = { "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta",
      "echo", "foxtrot", "golf", "hotel", "india", "juliet",
      "kilo", "lima", "mike", "november", "oscar", "papa",
      "quebec", "romeo", "sierra", "tango", "uniform",
      "victor", "whisky", "x-ray", "yankee", "zulu"
       };

int
main(void)
{
    ENTRY e, **ep;
    struct hsearch_data *htab;
    int i;
    int resultOfHcreate_r;
    resultOfHcreate_r=hcreate_r(30,htab);
    assert(resultOfHcreate_r!=0);
    hdestroy_r(htab);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

error in `hcreate_r`

How to use this `hcreate_r`?

and other question is that :

Could you privde the GNU extension C library examples ?
I think the document of GNU extension C library is not enough knowledge to write.

and I have many questions of how to use the extension C library .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you will need to add the `#define _GNU_SOURCE` macro in order to access the GNU extensions properly. ie:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <search.h>
```

Then you need to understand the documentation:

> Function: int hcreate_r (size_t nel, struct hsearch_data *htab)
>
> ```
> The hcreate_r function initializes the object pointed to by htab to contain a 
> hashing table with at least nel elements. So this
> function is equivalent to the hcreate function except that the
> initialized data structure is controlled by the user.
>
> This allows having more than one hashing table at one time. 
> The memory necessary for the struct hsearch_data object can be allocated
> dynamically. It must be initialized with zero before calling this
> function.
>
> The return value is non-zero if the operation was successful. 
> If the return value is zero, something went wrong, which probably means
> the programs ran out of memory.
> ```

So unlike `hcreate`, *you* are providing the hashing table data structures. Further, those structures should be initialised to zero. So then you probably want to do something like this:

```
//dynamically create a single table of 30 elements 
htab=calloc(1,sizeof(struct hsearch_data));
resultOfHcreate_r=hcreate_r(30,htab);

//do some stuff

//dispose of the hash table and free heap memory
hdestroy_r(htab);
free(htab)
```

Comment: hi violet313 , thanks . the code works. but htab=calloc(30,sizeof(struct hsearch_data)); just alloc the memory ,not initialised to zero. don't need to initialised to 0 ?

Comment: ah, thats the beauty of [calloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc); it zeros the memory for you ~& *iff* you're lucky with your `calloc` implementation *&* the moon is full *&* it's a thursday *&* you saw a magpie that day *&* your allocation is large enough to require whole pages,,, *then it might even be faster* than `malloc` + `memset` ~but in any case it's less to type so i like it ;)

Comment: Why don't you just go `struct hsearch_data htab; memset(&htab, 0, sizeof(htab)); result = hcreate_r(30, &htab);`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an hcreate_r variation of the hcreate example from the [man page](https://manual.cs50.io/3/hcreate).

It should compile and run and uses some of the ideas discussed here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <search.h>

char *data[] = { "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta",
      "echo", "foxtrot", "golf", "hotel", "india", "juliet",
      "kilo", "lima", "mike", "november", "oscar", "papa",
      "quebec", "romeo", "sierra", "tango", "uniform",
      "victor", "whisky", "x-ray", "yankee", "zulu"
       };

int
main(void)
{
    ENTRY e, *ep;
    struct hsearch_data *htab;
    int i;
    
    /*dynamically allocate memory for a single table.*/ 
    htab = (struct hsearch_data*) malloc( sizeof(struct hsearch_data) );
    /*zeroize the table.*/
    memset(htab, 0, sizeof(struct hsearch_data) );
    /*create 30 table entries.*/
    assert( hcreate_r(30,htab) != 0 );
    
    /*add data to 24 entries.*/
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        e.key = data[i];
        /* data is just an integer, instead of a
           pointer to something */
        e.data = (void *) i;
        
        /* there should be no failures */
        if (hsearch_r(e, ENTER, &ep, htab) == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "entry failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 22; i < 26; i++) {
        /* print two entries from the table, and
           show that two are not in the table */
        e.key = data[i];
        
        if (hsearch_r(e, FIND, &ep, htab) == 0) {
            ep = NULL;
        }
        printf("%9.9s -> %9.9s:%d\n", e.key,
               ep ? ep->key : "NULL", ep ? (int)(ep->data) : 0);
    }
    
    //dispose of the hash table and free heap memory
    hdestroy_r(htab);
    free(htab);
    
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: These examples will throw warnings on x86_64 machines and most probably on 32 bit machines as well.  An address is 8 bytes on x86_64, but an int is usually 4 bytes.  

You can suppress the warning by changing the int datatypes to long datatypes, which are also 8 bytes.  %ld is the printf format specifier for a long.

Comment: For a much more versatile, although nonstandard, solution check out [uthash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/), which is just a header file, no library linking, but provides many of the functions one would expect from a hash table implementation.