# glibc - list and other data structures implementations

Tags: c, linux, list, glibc

I fill like my google searching skills are poor right now, couldn't find a list implementation in glibc, found [hash](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hsearch) and [tree](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Tree-Search-Function) implementations but not a list one.

Is there any glibc implementation for that? I don't want to reformat the [linux kernel linked list](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) macros and use them in userspace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`insque(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/insque/) and [`remque(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/remque/)

Comment: No, it's a C API.  It would be pretty weird if it did.

Comment: How come I didn't know about these functions before? And why does `search.h` define the `struct qelem` structure with a trailing `char q_data[1];` element? That makes that definition less useful for embedding in a user's struct and has no benefit that I can think of off the top of my head (so I must be missing something, right?).

Comment: @MichaelBurr, old implementation, I guess.  The [POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/insque.html) has some more detail about that down in the "APPLICATION USAGE" section.

Answer (score 8):

There's `/usr/include/sys/queue.h` which contains various linked list variants.(more than the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/queue.3.html) documents)

Here's an example for a TAIL_QUEUE:
Run it through the preprocessor (gcc -E -c prog.c) to easier see how it
works under the hood)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>



struct Block {
    char text[64];
    //linked list entry
    TAILQ_ENTRY(Block) blocks;
};
struct File {
   char name[128];
   //list of blocks in the "file"
   TAILQ_HEAD(,Block) head; 
};


void add_block(struct File *f, const char *txt)
{
   struct Block *b = malloc(sizeof *b);
   strcpy(b->text,txt); 
   TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&f->head, b, blocks);
}

void print_file(struct File *f)
{
    struct Block *b;
    printf("File: %s\n", f->name);
    TAILQ_FOREACH(b, &f->head, blocks) {
        printf("Block: %s\n", b->text);
    }
}
void delete_block(struct File *f, const char *txt)
{
    struct Block *b, *next;
    for(b = TAILQ_FIRST(&f->head) ; b != NULL ; b = next) {
        next = TAILQ_NEXT(b, blocks);
        if(strcmp(b->text, txt) == 0) {
            TAILQ_REMOVE(&f->head, b, blocks);
            free(b);
        }
    }

}

void delete_all_blocks(struct File *f)
{
    struct Block *b;
    while((b = TAILQ_FIRST(&f->head))) {
        TAILQ_REMOVE(&f->head, b, blocks);
        free(b);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct File f;
    TAILQ_INIT(&f.head);
    strcpy(f.name,"Test.f");
    add_block(&f,"one");
    add_block(&f,"two");
    add_block(&f,"three");

    print_file(&f);

    puts("\nDeleting three");
    delete_block(&f, "three");
    print_file(&f);

    puts("\nAdding 2 blocks");
    add_block(&f,"three");
    add_block(&f,"three");
    print_file(&f);

    puts("\nDeleting three");
    delete_block(&f, "three");
    print_file(&f);

    delete_all_blocks(&f);


    return 0;
}
```