# printing certain words from list in alphabetical order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, linked-list

I'm going through a list of words and if a word meets certain criteria it is to be printed to the screen. The tricky bit is the order the words are to be printed to the screen is alphabetical. What's the best way of doing this? I'd guess sorting the list first would be inefficient so I'd opt for a linkedlist but sadly c [doesn't have one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001652/does-standard-c-library-provides-linked-list-etc-data-structures) :(

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

Comment: Unless it's a very long list, sorting is probably the best way and takes little time.

Comment: Just sort them.  The reality is that to accomplish your task you are going to sort them anyway even if you don't call whatever method you come up with a sort.  P.S. C has a linked list...millions of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to sort the words before you print them out. C provides a sorting function, called `qsort()`. It works on arrays, and needs to be passed a comparison function. Below is an example of using `qsort()` to sort an array of `int`.

```
static int cmp_int (const void *a, const void *b);

//...
    int arr[] = { 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5 };
    qsort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), sizeof(*arr), cmp_int);
```

The trick to implementing `cmp_int()` correctly is to realize that the types the comparison function receive is the same as the type of `&arr[0]`. Since `arr` is an array of `int`, this means that `cmp_int()` will receive `int *` types. This function is supposed to return a negative value if the first argument is less than the second, a positive value if the first argument is greater than the second, and 0 otherwise.

```
static int cmp_int (const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    return (*aa > *bb) - (*aa < *bb);
}
```